# How to set priorities for multiple threads in java

Tags: java

How does one set different priorities for different threads on JAVA?
Let us assume I have three threads A,B,C..and i want A to be of high priority..
How do I set the priority value in each case? Can I get a sample code for that?

Comment: `Thread.setPriority(Thread.MAX_Priority);`

Comment: Google firstly before asking question at SO

Answer (score 1):

Each thread have a priority. Priorities are represented by a number between 1 and 10. In most cases, thread scheduler schedules the threads according to their priority (known as preemptive scheduling).

There are 3 constant priorities defined in `Thread` class:

- `public static int MIN_PRIORITY`
- `public static int NORM_PRIORITY`
- `public static int MAX_PRIORITY`

You can use it as follows:

```
public static void main(String args[]){  
  Test t1 = new Test();  
  Test t2 = new Test();  
  t1.setPriority(Thread.MIN_PRIORITY);  
  t2.setPriority(Thread.MAX_PRIORITY);  
  t1.start();  
  t2.start();  
 }
```

But it is not guaranteed because it depends on JVM specification that which scheduling it chooses.

Read more [here](http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/threads/priority_what.shtml).

Answer (score 0):

You can just call `Thread.setPriority(int)` on your thread objects.

The value has to be between `Thread.MIN_PRIORITY` and `Thread.MAX_PRIORITY`